# How to install VS2008 on the D:\ drive instead of C:\ 

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am running out of space on the `C:\` drive, so I need to install it on the `D:\` drive. When I try to install it I am not able to change the installation path. Please help.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? _Why_ can't you change the path?

Answer (score 1):

When selecting the features to install you can change the drive they are installed to.

Some components can't be changed, as they need to be on the system volume.

See this [video](http://www.videotutorialzone.com/development-tools/visual-studio-2008/installing-microsoft-visual-studio-2008.html) - around 1:30 you can see at the bottom right of the screen which drive the selected feature will be installed to. At this point you can change the drive.